# Using f[i] = x + y in MatLab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm new to Matlab and I have to do a project where I use curved integrals. For that, I need to start at point Z0 and get 4 other **random** points. I know how to get them using `randn(1)*Var` & `complex(x,y)` but my question is, is there a way to define, `z[i] = Real(z) + Imag(z)*i` instead of having to type,Z1, Z2 etc...
I have found that I can use `eval(sprintf('z%d = complex(x,y)',d))` but that it's not recomended.
All suggestions will be more than welcome!

```
clear all;
close all;

global z x y
z = x+y*1i;

%z = complex(x,y);
fun = @(z) 1./(2*pi*z);



for d = 1:4
    x = randn(1)*5;
    y = randn(1)*5;
    zr = real(z);
    zi = imag(z);
    eval(sprintf('z%d = complex(x,y)',d))
    
end

syms z(x,y) [1 4]
z0 = complex(4,0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the array indexing operator (parentheses in Matlab) `z_array(d) = complex(x, y)`?

```
z_array = [];
for d = 1:4
    x = randn(1)*5;
    y = randn(1)*5;
    z_array(d) = x + 1i * y;    
end
```

Alternatively, instead of looping, you could create the entire array in one shot:

```
num_vals = 10;

x_array = randn([num_vals, 1]); % Make a 10x1 random array
y_array = randn([num_vals, 1]); % Make a 10x1 random array
z_array = x_array + 1i * y_array;
```

Note: `z_array = complex(x_array, y_array)` might be faster than `z_array = x_array + 1i * y_array` <sup>[Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67289531/using-fi-x-y-in-matlab/67290106?noredirect=1#comment118940419_67290106) [Cris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo)!</sup>

The second approach will be much *much* faster if you have large arrays, and works for element-wise addition for arrays in general.

Comment: `z_array = complex(x_array, y_array)` might be faster. Not sure if this is still the case, but it used to be.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I remembered one of the two was faster but I couldn't remember which one. It's been a while since I used Matlab, and I hear there's lots of optimizations in newer versions, so they might well have identical performance now. Thanks for the note though :)

Comment: Indeed, every version of MATLAB has more optimizations, you kinda have to test things for the particular version you're using, if it's critical code. Also, complex number representation has changed internally in 2018, so all bets are off. :)

Comment: that's amazing! it works flawlessly! I was thinking like in Java, where you can create an array and say array [I] = rand_X + I rand_Y , the values in the current Rand and it being inside a forloop, would change the values every time it ran

Comment: Also, I have to get a point in each quadrant, so in +x+y, -x+y, -x-y and +x-y, in this order. Is there a way to do it with this method or will I end up having to go manual?

Comment: @Box _"array [I] = rand_X + I rand_Y"_ Yes, that is how the first example works! Many times, the loopy way you're used to from Java is _slower_ than the vectorized way in Matlab which I demonstrate in the second example.

Comment: Re. one point in each quadrant: You only want four points, so just go manual.